# A simpler expression that is always smaller or larger

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I have this function
$$\small A(n)=-\frac{2 b_0 \left(2 - 2 l (-2 + n) - 3 l^2 (-1 + n) + l^3 (-1 + n)^2 \right) + 
  l \left(2 + 3 l - l^2 (-2 + n) \right) \sigma^2 \log\left(\frac{q}{1-q}\right)}{
 2 (1 + l) (2 + 2 l + l^2)}$$
and I need simpler functions such as $A'(n)=\frac{T}{n}$ where $T$ is a constant (can be related to the values of $\sigma,q,l$) that are always smaller or larger, i.e. two functions $A'(n)$ and $A''(n)$ such that $A'(n)>A(n)>A''(n)$ for all $n>0$ (or $n>N$ for some large enough $N$).

What would be the best way? I have several expressions like this one and I need this approach to make simpler some probabilistic analyses I need. 
For record, I can use Mathematica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. Your function is a quadratic polynomial in $n$. You can not estimate it from above or below by a hyperbolic function.

Comment: I might need to restate the question then since I did this for another expression. I don't care actually how the "simpler" function looks like, I just need to have, say, a linear function of n that falls always below. Now, there may be infinitely many such functions but if I have a systematic way than I might use it to find ones that are good for my use (to include in calculating the probabilities as n grows, in particular).

Comment: Well, write your function as $an^2 + bn + c$, where $a,b,c$ are fractions. Then it is already pretty simple. Next, you can consider if you want your estimate on a particular domain, or on all of $\mathbb{R}$. Depending on the answer, you might be able to round $a$ to an integer, and get rid of $b$ and $c$.